# How to distribute n questions to n students with all students having the same questions but in different orders.

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

I am building an online exam platform. Let's say I have an MCQ test of 20 questions and say 60 students in a class. Is there a mathematical function or probability that I can compute to in a way that each student receives all 20 questions but randomized uniquely such that question 1 for Student A may be question 12 for Student B and so on and so forth.

Comment: If your intention is to prevent collusion between students, giving them the same questions but in a different order is not likely to be very effective.  All it means is that instead of sharing just the list of answers, they must share the questions as well.

Comment: Well @Robert Israel not necessarily. If the questions are randomized so too could the answers be. Its not a full proof method of but its a small but effective way to reduce the rate of collusion. A student under normal exam tension is most likely not to spell out the whole answer but give the letters of the answers. So if someone ask for the answer of question 1, he may get an answer say B, which may be C for another person on question 4. So either way its a small step if reducing cheating.

Comment: If there are multiple-choice answers, scramble the candidate answers as well.  It won't prevent collusion, but it will add an extra burden for students and hence increase the chance of an error, and time penalty for those trying to cheat.  If you really have automated control over problem creation, mix up terms.  Even for the identical technical question, change "If Bob gives Mary three apples..." to "If Mary gives Bob three oranges..."  That REALLY confuses the lowest-performing students trying to cheat... they cannot even tell if these are the "same" question!

Comment: I guess that kind of automation "If Bob gives Mary three apples"...to "If Mary gives Bob three oranges"..mixing questions like this will need some sort of AI system to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to give each student the questions in a random order.  For each student, draw a random number on $[1,20]$ for the first question, then on $[1,19]$ for the second one (choosing among the ones remaining for that student) and so on.  Assuming your random number generator is not badly messed up, the chance of two students getting the same list is small.  This won't guarantee that each question comes first for three students, but do you care about that?

Comment: Well it's possible for some questions to repeat in a certain order depending on the total number of students but am looking for a scenario where we'll have the least occurrence of repeating order of questions

Comment: You need to carefully think about what you want.  "Least occurrences of repeating order of questions" is not a specification.  Do you mean that if one student gets question 3 after question 5, no other student should get that pair sequentially?  You can't do that with two questions, but you could with three.  Does that really matter?

Comment: I understand your point. It doesn't really matter.